# How can I combine these two queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, I'm a noob, I accept that. But I'm trying to combine these two queries and for some reason I can't understand how.

Query 1.

```
select t.id from tickets t
```

Query 2.

```
SELECT name 
FROM groups 
WHERE id = (
            SELECT DISTINCT immediateparentid 
            FROM cachedgroupmembers c
            LEFT JOIN groups g
            ON c.groupid = g.id
            LEFT JOIN tickets t
            ON t.id = g.instance
            WHERE t.Id = 1234
            AND g.type = 'AdminCc'
            AND immediateparentid <> c.groupid
        )
```

The ticket id in the first query is being used in the where clause of the second. Is there a way to combine these two queries?

Comment: if you remove t.id = 1234 from the where clause, you should get all t.id's as in the first query? Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: For what output? Since you filtered it, you know its value is 1234.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        g.name,
        (SELECT id FROM tickets) as ID
FROM groups as g
WHERE id = (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT immediateparentid 
            FROM cachedgroupmembers c
            LEFT JOIN groups g ON c.groupid = g.id
            LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.id = g.instance
            WHERE t.Id = ID
            AND g.type = 'AdminCc'
            AND immediateparentid <> c.groupid
        )
```

This is a dependant subquery